# Android exisiting Wifi Scan

Tags: android, eclipse, wifi, adt, network-scan

I'm writing an app (which is currently unfinished) that should run in the background and scan for all the Wifis in range, using the WifiManager as usual, nothing special.

I was wondering: An Android device scans for Wifis every 5 seconds or so, to check for Saved Networks and connect automatically to one of them (probably the closest).
Is there a way to use this existing Wifi Scan , so that I do not need to use my own and eventually slow down the phone because of 2 existing wifi scans? Can I grab all the scanned Wifis once every 5 secs when the phone automatically scans?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

to receive scan results.

It gets WiFi Scan itself and you don't have to call getScan func.